# Issue with back button title in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have 2 `UIViewController`. I have just done a simple task.

Move from first view controller to second view controller.

First View Controller's Name : "My Information"

Issue is when I reach to the 2nd View Controller then I found back button title as "Back"

[image]

When I turn the simulator to landscape view then back button title is as "My Information"

[image]

What is the issue there? I could not understand.

Comment: Where do you set your title for view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the title is too long. Try setting it to a shorter string, or set your own custom back button.

Answer (score 2):

In "My Information" view controller add below code.

1) In `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                     style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];
}
```

[image: My Information]

[image]

Comment: This way you loose `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

@Dharmesh, please look at the code here [code sample](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2857188/CustomNavBar.zip) this shows after you change the mode to landscapeback button remains same.